# Slicing a dataframe based on range of time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to Pandas. I have a set of Excel data read into a dataframe as follows:

```
TimeReceived    A   B
08:00:01.010    70  40
08:00:01.050    80  50
08:01:01.100    50  20
08:01:01.150    40  30
```

I want to compute the average for columns A & B based on time intervals of 100 ms.
The output in this case would be :

```
TimeReceived    A   B
 08:00:01.000   75  45
 08:00:01.100   45  25
```

I have set the 'TimeReceived' as  a Date-Time index:

```
df = df.set_index (['TimeReceived'])
```

I can select rows based on predefined time ranges but I cannot  do computations on time intervals as shown above.

Comment: so does `df.resample('100ms').mean().dropna()`work?

Comment: Does 'Timereceived '  has constant intervals? Like after 150 its sure it will be 200?

Comment: Yes, it is constant intervals

Comment: @EdChum: yes, it works! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a`DatetimeIndex` you can then use `resample` to up or down sample your data to a new frequency. This will introduce `NaN` rows where there are gaps but you can drop these using `dropna`:

```
df.resample('100ms').mean().dropna()
```